# How to create service in react native for both android and ios to detect call incoming and out coming call to record user calls

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on react native app where I need to detect users' calls and record the user calls. To record the call first I need to detect calls and for that, I need a service that runs all time even app is in the background or closed. I used this library for calls recording

```
import CallRecord from 'react-native-call-record';

CallRecord.getAll({}).then(obj => {
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cannot access native call audio on iOS.